# Woocommerce review order total hook is echoing result twice

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I want to get the cart total figure for which I am using the following code in my `functions.php`:

```
function display_total(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $newTotal = $woocommerce->cart->get_total();

    echo $newTotal;
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total', 'display_total');
```

Instead of displaying the amount once, it does it twice like `$18.00$18.00`.

Doing a `var_dump` too results in 2 lines of HTML:

```
D:\Wordpress\wp-content\themes\new_theme\functions.php:161:string '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>18.00</bdi></span>' (length=128)

D:\Wordpress\wp-content\themes\new_theme\functions.php:161:string '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>18.00</bdi></span>' (length=128)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Ruvee Thanks but already tried. 'Return', on the contrary, doesn't display anything.

Comment: How about trying to echo the value in the middle of a table, like this: `echo '<tr><td >' . $newTotal . '</td></tr>';`

Comment: @Ruvee Thank you very much. Working now. But what was the reason for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Echo the value in a table row, so that it won't echo it twice. So your code would be something like this:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total', 'display_total');

function display_total(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $newTotal = $woocommerce->cart->get_total();

    echo '<tr><td >' . $newTotal . '</td></tr>';
};
```

And the reason is, `woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total` hook is being used in a table, therefore adding your value between a `tr` and `td` tag would result in echoing the value once.